# Cypress | check that search keywords match the value of any td of the displayed trs

Tags: datatables, cypress

I'm testing a search functionality that filters the entered characters against users' Firstname, Lastname, role, or email.

I have a `table` with multiple `tr` and each `tr` has multiple `td`.

I want to assert that the returned rows contain a value in any `td` that matches the entered keyword.

I created the below helper function but `cy.get('td').contains(searchKeyword);` causes the browser to hang up. any idea what could be the solution here.

```
 assertCorrectFilterResults(searchKeyword: string) {
            this.elements.tableBody().find("tr").then(rows => {
                rows.toArray().forEach(row => {
                    cy.get('td').contains(searchKeyword);
                })
            });
        };
```

My helper was inspired from the solution mentioned here [How to get the total number of Rows in a table | Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63086695/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-rows-in-a-table-cypress/)

Table Structure
[image]

Comment: can you share the html of your table.

Comment: @AlapanDas question updated.

Comment: So you have to loop through all the `td` element in all rows `tr` and check whether you can find the searchKeyword ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case if you directly want to look into the `td` elements you can directly loop over them.

For exact Match with the `searchKeyword`

```js
cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr td').each(($ele) => {
  if($ele.text().trim() == searchKeyword){
    expect($ele.text().trim()).to.equal(searchKeyword)  //Assertion for exact text
  }
})
```

For partial match with the `searchKeyword`

```js
cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr td').each(($ele) => {
  if($ele.text().trim().includes(searchKeyword)){
    expect($ele.text().trim()).to.include(searchKeyword)  //Assertion for partial text
  }
})
```

Comment: One more question 
I need to get the index of the `tr` in this case as well trigger another action on a button another `td` in this `tr`

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping each row.

This will test that all the rows contain the searchword.

```js
assertCorrectFilterResults(searchKeyword: string) {
  cy.get('tbody').find("tr").then(rows => {
    rows.toArray().forEach(row => {

      cy.wrap(row).contains(searchKeyword);  // test that one of child <td> has searchKeyword 

    })
  });
};
```

You can assert that a parent element "contains" text that is inside a child element, so

```html
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Find me!</td>
</tr>
```

asserting on `<tr>` with `.contains(...)` will check all the `<td>`.

---

**Additional Note**

When you do `cy.get('td')` inside the forEach, Cypress actually searches from the `cy.root()` element (by default it's the `<body>` element).

So another way to do it is to change the root element using `.within()`

```js
assertCorrectFilterResults(searchKeyword: string) {
  cy.get('tbody').find("tr").then(rows => {
    rows.toArray().forEach(row => {

      cy.wrap(row).within(() => {
        cy.get('td').contains(searchKeyword);  // now get works only in this row
      })

    })
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this valuable info about wrap() and within() context, however, it is still timeout at my end. I updated the question with my table structure.

Comment: I did a simple test using `cy.get('tbody')` instead of `this.elements.tableBody()` and the result looks ok. Can you post the code for `this.elements.tableBody()`? Can take a look to see if that causes the problem.

Comment: elements = {
    tableBody: () => cy.get('tbody[class="MuiTableBody-root"]'),
}

Comment: I see that the assertion failure returns the `td`s in the context.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a button in another `<td>` of the row:

```js
cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr')  // note - end this selector at tr
.each(($tr, rowIndex) => {            // row index is passed as 2nd param

  if ($tr.text().includes(searchKeyword)) {

    cy.wrap($tr).within(() => {
      cy.get('td').eq(3)  // for example 4th col has button
        .find('button')   
        .click()
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: This gets all `tr` in the app so it causes the browser to hangs

Comment: It's the same as the other example, except splitting the tr and td selection so you can get the row index, and also access the button column.

Comment: How many tables are there on the page?

Comment: Just one table but It has more than 250 th, I'm not sure is that the cause of the. timeout or something wrong with the code.

Comment: I was trying but no way :'( 


```cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr')
        //     .filter(`:contains(${email})`)
        //     .each($tr => {
        //         cy.wrap($tr).find('button[title = "Delete"]')
        //             .click()
        //         })
    }```